# I cannot upload a file with python using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to upload a file with python using selenium.
This is the code that I use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

file = "C:\\Users\\Marcelino\\Downloads\\issues.xlsx"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'E:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get("https://host.boostmediagroup.com:2083/cpsess3744252593/frontend/paper_lantern/filemanager/upload-ajax.html?file=&fileop=&dir=%2Fhome%2Fsftpgoogletxl%2Fupdate_drive%2Fsource&dirop=&charset=&file_charset=&baseurl=&basedir=")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/input").send_keys("sftpgoogletxl")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[4]/input").send_keys("I5ztfn=FR_1K")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/div/button").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/button").send_keys(file)
```

But when I run the code the specific file is not uploaded on the site even if the code was "Process finished with exit code 0" and I don't know what to do anymore, I was tried with pyautogui but I use this bot on a VM and when I run on VM the script is not working because the VM is locked.
Any other ideas? Thank you in advanced
Here is a video with behavior:
[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1km94WmH2MtnCpd0SNPKoIuy7lGoBwBJL/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

To upload the file directly you should use input element with type of file.
Try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']").send_keys(file)
```

Comment: Same result like in the video

Comment: Don't exit the test immediately after sending the file to the input element. Put a delay and a braking point, see if it uploads the file.

Comment: I don't know how to put the braking point

Comment: I add this
`time.sleep(10)
breakpoint()
`

Comment: no, it's not a command. google "pycharm how to set breakpoint"

Comment: Or simply put `time.sleep(1000)` alternatively

Comment: Same result the file is not added

Comment: maybe the file type is not supported? Maybe it should be a picture or something else?

Comment: If I add manually it works or if I use pyautogui is work but when I want to use the selenium is not working.

Comment: Strange. Currently have no idea, sorry. Please let me know when you found the issue what was it